# Excel VBA Application.iferror() is not handling the error

Tags: excel, vba

I have a function that has a vlookup in it.
The vlookup works if the lookup value is in the target array.
If the lookup value is not in the target array, I need it to return a 0.
Currently, when I run the function with a lookup value that is not in the array, the function just errs and ends.  No messages.
Here is my code.

```
Function myPrice(myPart As String, myVol As Integer)

    Application.Volatile

    Dim myCol As Integer
    Dim myCavity As Integer
    Dim myCycleTime As Integer
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim myVal As Double

    Set wb = Workbooks("AdvancedQuote.xlsm")
    Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    With ws

    myVal = Application.IfError(Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup("Four", .Range("TestTable"), 2, 0), 678)

    myCol = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(myPart, .Range("Item_Name"), 0)
    myCavity = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(.Range("Molding_Data"), Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("Cavities", .Range("pRows"), 0), myCol)
    myCycleTime = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(.Range("Molding_Data"), Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("Cycle Time", .Range("pRows"), 0), myCol)

    End With

    myPrice = myCavity * myCycleTime / myVol

End Function
```

The line that fails is the myVal =  line.
Is there a need to set up the 'on error' to allow the IfError to handle the error?

Or, how can I accomplish this task.
Rich

Answer (score 4):

The WorksheetFunction property causes the program to break when there's an error.  Therefore, use the VLOOKUP method of the Application object instead...

```
myVal = Application.IfError(Application.VLookup("Four", .Range("TestTable"), 2, 0), 678)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the code below to trap an error if `Application.VLookup` doesn't find `"Four"` in `.Range("TestTable")`.

```
If IsError(Application.VLookup("Four", .Range("TestTable"), 2, 0)) Then ' Vlookup raised an error
    myVal = 678
Else ' Vlookup was successful
    myVal = Application.VLookup("Four", .Range("TestTable"), 2, 0)
End If
```

Comment: Now I have found that the iferror() is not handling a div/0 error. Is there something special about catching this error?

Comment: Check [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/on-error-statement) out.

Comment: @UGP check what ? `On Error Resume Next` ? I have "heard" of it ;) I rather use other ways to trap errors, unless I have to.